# IPython Notebook not displaying graphs correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have Python installed using Miniconda on OS X 10.9. This is admittedly a minor issue, but it's inconvenient nonetheless. When I use the IPython notebook, I can't get matplotlib to display the graphs correctly. The graphs show up behind the browser window, and the only way to view them is to hide the browser window. If I use Mission Control to the select the window with the graph, it immediately disappears behind the browser window.

Comment: what backend are you using? simplest fix would be to use `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the only issue I have is that inline keeps you from scaling the resolution (you can expand the image, but it has the same number of pixels and same shape.) You also can't zoom in.

I'm using the Mac OS X backend.

Comment: I guess you can try playing with different backends.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, thanks! I was able to use the tk backend, which didn't have the same issue